# HTML Interface for Java based Server Management

Tags: java, rest, jetty

Say I have a `Java HTTP server` which serves `REST APIs` like `GET/PUT/POST` etc based on `Jetty`. I want to create a `HTML` interface for this server so that I can turn on/off  certain features, control settings, surface server metrics etc through it.

Is there any such Java library I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 main directions to go:

1. Jetty has a built-in servlet-jsp engine support that you can use for your dynamic configuration HTML pages. You can make your configuration in jsp supported forms and dispatch their processing to servlets to make the configuration model change.
2. An other way is to extend your REST API with the configuration relevant part and interact with it from javascript from config HTML pages.

You do not need to deploy further jars neither for 1 nor for 2. 
1. is built in
2. is already deployed by you because you are using a REST implementation already

- If you have a complex configuration logic with more HTML pages you might consider using JSF instead of JSP.